# Are keyboard hooks inherently malicious?

Tags: windows, antivirus, antimalware, keyloggers

My software is using low-level keyboard and mouse Win32 hooks for legitimate reasons (if it's any relevant, it's for determining a change in the caret position of the active code pane in the VBA IDE).

Windows Defender is flagging my installer as "malicious":

[image: Trojen:Win32/Fathale.B!plock]

Same with Symantec, and probably other antivirus/malware detection tools too.

I've had similar false-positive "malware alert" issues before with Symantec, supposedly due to the file being recent and/or having very few downloads, but these older versions didn't use a Win32 low-level keyboard hook, and AFAIK weren't flagged as "malicious" by Windows Defender.

I have **NOT** implemented a key logger; I do **NOT** handle WM messages sent anywhere other than the VBE's active code pane, and I have **NOT** intentionally packaged malware with my installer.

Does merely using a keyboard hook inherently make software "malicious"? Or is there a way to use them that doesn't trigger a malware alert?

Or does "Trojan:Win32/Fathale.B!plock" have completely nothing to do with that and it turns out there *is* something that *somehow* managed to sneak into my installer package?

Comment: FWIW the release page is [here](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/releases/tag/v2.0.1a.pre), and the software is open-source, if anyone feels like dissecting the actual thing.

Comment: I am getting same thing. Did you use innoSetup?

Comment: @xenon yes, I'm using InnoSetup to create the installer. InstallShield was a complete nightmare with COM registration, and using WiX was going to be a project of its own; InnoSetup made everything relatively simple, and we had an installer that worked for both 32-bit and 64-bit environment and VBA hosts.

Comment: I'm also using a keyboard hook for reasons other than key-logging. I imagine this is happening quite often and to be honest, the fact that a keyboard hook is not detected scares me. This has to make someone wonder how many apps are in fact using keyboard hooks. In my opinion, a keylogger is the worst of malicious software. It is a major violation of privacy. My question is, how would I even detect if an app has a keyboard hook?

Answer (score 3):

The biggest clue came in a comment:

> *I am getting same thing. Did you use innoSetup?*

And I did.

The conversation [here](http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=103838&group=jrsoftware.innosetup#103838) points to a problem involving Inno Setup seemingly generating what appears to be a matching signature for a `trojan:Win32/Fathale.B!plock`.

Submit the installer to the [Microsoft Malware Protection Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/portal/submission/submit.aspx).

If your installer is indeed "clean", you should eventually get a response along these lines:

> The submitted file is Clean.
>   We will remove the detection for this sample.

Nothing to do with keyhooks =)

Comment: For the record I'm also getting this, though not using innoSetup but writing WiX by hand. The resolution is the same though (submit the installer) ...